# Convert an array of string arrays to a hash of string and float in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following array of arrays.

```
>> gold_prices

=> [["2011-01-11", "134.91"], ["2011-01-10", "134.12"], 
   ["2011-01-07", "133.58"], ["2011-01-06", "133.83"]]
```

What is the cleanest way to convert each sub-array into a hash of :string => float?

Comment: Do you want 4 hashes with 1 key or 1 hash with 4 keys?

Comment: One hash with four key,value pairs in this example. The 'date' is the string key and the 'price' is the float value.

Comment: It's always helpful to supply an example of your desired result. That will help avoid questions like Skilldrick's.

Comment: @TinMan, will do in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>> gold_prices = Hash[gold_prices.map {|date, price| [date, price.to_f]}]

=> {"2011-01-11" => 134.91, "2011-01-10" => 134.12,
    "2011-01-07" => 133.58, "2011-01-06" => 133.83}
```

Comment: Very nice - I didn't know about that syntax!

Comment: You got a clean answer before I could edit my question to manufacture the hash you created. Thanks much.

Comment: Probably not a big deal, but note that this particular form only works in Ruby 1.8.7+; for earlier versions you need `Hash[ *foo.map{...}.flatten ]`

Comment: @Phrogz has the *foo C-pointer-looking-syntax an artifact now or is it still used in Ruby 1.8.7+?

Comment: @Milktrader `Hash.[]` also still accepts an even number of arguments: `Hash[1,2,3,4] #=> {1=>2, 3=>4}`. The _"C-pointer-looking-syntax"_ is known as a "splat" in Ruby. Here it is taking a single array of values and passing them as individual arguments to a method. Ruby 1.8.7/1.9 added the more convenient form seen in the answer here, where it can also now take an array of two-value arrays.

Comment: Thanks @Phrogz for the explanation. @LBg, thanks for this compact piece of code. What is also cool is that if you drop the Hash [] bookends, you get an array of arrays where the first element of each sub-array is a string and second element is a float.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

gold_prices = [["2011-01-11", "134.91"], ["2011-01-10", "134.12"], 
  ["2011-01-07", "133.58"], ["2011-01-06", "133.83"]]

h = {}
gold_prices.each { | date, quote | h[date] = quote.to_f }

p h
# {"2011-01-06"=>133.83, "2011-01-07"=>133.58, ...
```

Comment: The quote needs to be a float.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy to remedy.

Answer (score 1):

For the 4 hashes with one key you could do:

```
gold_prices.collect { |item| { item.first => item.last.to_f } }
```